# Is it possible to make stains from a fluid simulation?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm working on a fluid simulation and want it to look like wine pouring into the cup and overflowing, but I've been looking for ways to add stains on the cup from the fluid simulation. Can you do that?

Comment: Maybe look into [Dynamic Paint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/dynamic_paint/index.html)? Not sure if it works directly with fluid objects though

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I tried doing that but it doesn't show up on the rendered version of the cup. :(

Comment: You have to actually use the generated texture and use it in your material

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making stains from fluid stimulation would hamper your scene performance as it would cost too many polygons (Fluids are expensive) and also it will be really difficult to do something like that as fluids are meant to flow not stay on a mesh like stains so the simplest and most effective way is to use texture projection to project stains on your mesh or you can also make custom texture combined with some roughness and bump maps to make some part of your texture look like stain.